# Trouble getting "new look" Google Maps embedded

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-embed

Building a website for a client I would need to embed GMaps on a regular basis. For the purpose, I use maplace.js.

It all works rather nicely but I have noticed something odd.

I have enabled the new "look" of google maps on my Google account, so now it looks very nice and clean:

[image: New look Google maps]

Here, I can generate an iFrame for manual embedding of a GMap on my website, keeping that new, clean look and rather convenient "get directions" overlay:

[image]

However, when using maplace.js (and thus, in effect the maps API) I still get the old look and noe of the nice and clean controls:

[image]

I have searched high and low for a way to make thinks look the same as in the Google generated frames, but no luck.

These are the includes I use to get things done:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry&v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/maplace.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the CSS that is applied to the map:

```
#gmap {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And the actual map embedding:

```
<script>
new Maplace({
    map_options: {
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        draggable: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },
    visualRefresh: true,
    locations: [

            {lat: 50.871197, lon:  4.696941000000038, zoom: 15}



    ]
}).Load();
</script>
```

Anybody have thoughts on this?

Comment: "v=3.exp" (i.e. in your script src URL) should use the latest version of the Google Maps API, but have you tried using "v=3.17"? I know both should give you an up to date version, but it's worth a check!

Comment: Unfortunately they haven't updated their API with this new user interface yet. You can see on Google's own API v3 page that none of the [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) use the new UI. What they do seem to be pushing is a new Embed API, which DOES allow for the new UI while giving more control over embedded maps. See their offical blog post about it [here](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ca/2014/03/adding-new-google-maps-to-your-website.html) and the developer's page about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/).

Comment: New UI is not always part of API as from Beta version the UI can not be applied to API there are many things involved that might bug later, so stick to the old UI you receive for now and one is always allowed to customize the API refer adding [control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-options) in google Map API you can also [customize](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) for more help please post working fiddle

Comment: I will like to emphasize on the API type, its [Google Map Javascript API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript) which renders differently, you can check my [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/sQJ3k/1/) using same API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out (actually it is odd nobody else seems to have done so already).

The "new look" maps I refer to in my question are generated as part of the *[Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#api_key)*.

This API offers a number of benefits (apart from the nice look and context for the user looking at them):

- No usage/traffic limits
- Context for the user looking at the map is provided if that user is logged in to his/her account

Furthermore, it seems easy enough to embed this sort of map from any given content manager if you intend to use them on your site. This is because the src attribute of the  to embed them always has following layout:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/MODE?key=API_KEY&parameters
```

Which, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#api_key) is as follows:

- {MODE}: is one of place, directions, search, or view.
- {API_KEY} is your free API key.
- Parameters include optional parameters

The provided examples seem to show that it should be easy enough to e.g. link content fields of your CMS to the {MODE} field of the iframe src attribute:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY&q=Fisht+Olympic+Stadium,Sochi+Russia
```

Which is all I ever wanted to achieve. It seems I was just overly focused on the Maps API itself and somehow mist the other stuff :-/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same on a website that I was working on. We found really useful that little star to save the location on users Google Maps Favourites, then I realise that the `iframe` uses a different server side configuration than thoses `API` availables for us. We also checked the changelog of the JavaScript versions and unfortunately there isn't such feature available now.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog